# Is there a way to freeze Rails, Bundler, and everything into a self contained project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bundler, bundle

I ran into issues recently for having Bundler 1.1.3 and then using RVM use Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.0 because there was an older project that uses 1.9.2@rails300 -- it kept on saying bundler was the wrong version or something and there didn't seem like there was an easy solution.

Is there actually a way to freeze Rails, Bundler, and almost everything into a self contained project?   I think the sqlite or mysql server or executable doesn't need to be frozen as they conform to the same commands... but probably it is good to also freeze the gems that is the layer that talks to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified what your error was with bundler, it's hard to be too helpful, but you can accomplish most of this with your Gemfile and the rest of it with RVM. You can specify the required version of a gem like this:

```
gem "rails", "3.2.3"
```

This is all in the [docs for bundler](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) by the way. This is practically the whole point of bundler -- to ensure that your application's dependencies are handled in a consistent fashion.

Then, if you need a specific version of ruby for some reason, just dump that in your rvmrc, and you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

Because of bundler, it's now possible to freeze everything except the version of ruby, bundler, and gem.  These must have self consistant versions.

If you have multiple versions of bunder in your gem set, you can specify the version of bundler to use as the first argument.

```
bundle _1.1.3_ ...
```

If the problem is that there is an older project with uses the rails300 gem set, so you cannot change the versions in that gem set, then use rvm to create a new gem set for ruby 1.9.  However, if the versions of ruby, gem, and bundler don't agree for you, they won't work for the older project either, so you probably need to fix this.

You can freeze your gems, (and Rails is just a gem or collection of gems), by doing

```
bundle package
```

see the [docs for bundler](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) for more information.  Even if you are using gemsets in rvm, you still need to package your bundle, because gem versions are dynamically determined on start up even in rvm.